# Update Multiple Table while looping on them using a cursor (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, cursor, multiple-tables

I don't know if the title reflects what I'm asking, but I have multiple tables that I want to update using a field from a table that I'll call **"UPDATE_DATA_TABLE"**. The probleme is I'm trying to configure an sql job to do so. I can update one single table but can't make the job navigate through all the tables, I tried to passe the name of each table in variable, but nor the select nor the update is allowed when the name of tha table is a variable.

Here is what I've done so:

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE @temp_data NVARCHAR(256)
  DECLARE @temp_camp NVARCHAR(256)
  DECLARE @temp_indice INT
  DECLARE @total INT
  DECLARE @id INT = 1
  DECLARE @iter INT = 0
  DECLARE @TempCustomer TABLE(
    INDICE_TEMP INT NOT NULL,
    INDICE INT NOT NULL,
    DATAMEMO NVARCHAR(20))
  DECLARE @tab NVARCHAR(256)


  INSERT INTO @TempCustomer SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY INDICE ASC) AS Row,indice,DATAMEMO FROM TABLE_TO_UPDATE WHERE NIVABS >= 5
  SET @total = (SELECT count(*) FROM @TempCustomer)

  WHILE @iter < @total
   BEGIN
    SET @temp_indice =(SELECT INDICE FROM @tempCustomer WHERE INDICE_TEMP = @id)
    SET @temp_data = (SELECT DATAMEMO FROM @tempCustomer WHERE INDICE_TEMP = @id)


    IF @temp_data LIKE '*!01%'
      UPDATE TABLE_TO_UPDATE SET DATAMEMO = UDT.SDA2 FROM 
      UPDATE_DATA_TABLE UDT WHERE @temp_indice = 
      TABLE.INDICE
    ELSE IF @temp_data LIKE '*!02%'
      UPDATE TABLE_TO_UPDATE SET DATAMEMO = UDT.SDA3 FROM 
      UPDATE_DATA_TABLE UDT WHERE @temp_indice = 
      TABLE.INDICE
    ELSE IF @temp_data LIKE '*!03%'
      UPDATE TABLE_TO_UPDATE SET DATAMEMO = UDT.SDA4 FROM 
      UPDATE_DATA_TABLE UDT WHERE @temp_indice = 
      TABLE.INDICE
    ELSE IF @temp_data LIKE '*!04%'
      UPDATE TABLE_TO_UPDATE SET DATAMEMO = UDT.SDA5 FROM 
      UPDATE_DATA_TABLE UDT WHERE @temp_indice = 
      TABLE.INDICE
    ELSE IF @temp_data LIKE '*!05%'
      UPDATE TABLE_TO_UPDATE SET DATAMEMO = UDT.SDA1 FROM 
      UPDATE_DATA_TABLE UDT WHERE @temp_indice = 
      TABLE.INDICE

  SET @id = @id +1
  SET @iter = @iter +1
 END
END
```

A collegue adviced me to use cursors for such task, but I don't really know how.

**EDIT:**

- ***TABLE_TO_UPDATE***'s structure:

  1. *Column 1:* Indice
  2. *Column 2:* FirstName
  3. *Column 3:* LastName
  4. *Column 4:* DATAMEMO
- ***UPDATE_DATA_TABLE***'s structure:

  1. *Column 1:* Campaign
  2. *Column 2:* SDA1
  3. *Column 3:* SDA2
  4. *Column 4:* SDA3
  5. *Column 5:* SDA4
  6. *Column 6:* SDA5

There is another table (Campaign_Table), containing all the names of the campaigns/tables (the name of campaigns is similaire to the name of tables).

- ***Campaign_Table***'s structure:

  1. *Column 1:* ID
  2. *Column 2:* Campaign_name

What I tired to do is to fetch the name of the campaign to modify, and then pass it on a variable to replace **"TABLE_TO_UPDATE"** in the code.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We need to see some details about your system to be able to help. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: @BaDumTss . . . Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the *logic* you want to implement would help.  Using cursors is generally *bad* advice, and I don't see an *a priori* reason why they would be necessary.

Comment: This feels like a pure SQL solution is available without procedural extensions.

Comment: No need to manage any cursor or loop as per your mentioned query. Please provide us your table structure and requirement, so we can help with such solution.

Comment: Hi, I just edited the post and added the tables structures "I couldn't post the code nor a screenshot of the tables due to confidentiality restrictions". I hope I gave you the informations you need.